# Correct way to return function value instead of binding in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I can't seem to find a concise answer to this question. What is the correct coffeescriptic way to return the value from _otherInstanceMethod when calling @_instanceMethod instead of the function binding itself?

```
x = _instanceMethod: () ->
    @_otherInstanceMethod key: 'value'
```

Edit (thanks commenters)

This returns:

```
x = function () {
    [...] # function body omitted    
});
```

Instead of

```
x = 'some value returned by _otherInstanceMethod'
```

I would like the value to be returned instead of the function binding to _otherInstanceMethod

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly is wrong? The question doesn't seem to me very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Being totally new to Coffeescript, this was my fault. I was calling the instance method like:

```
@_instanceMethod
```

instead of

```
@_instanceMethod()
```

Sorry for the trouble, voting to delete

Answer (score -1):

In CoffeeScript `@something` translated into `this.something` regardless of the underlying variable type. This means you can use `@` only in conjuction with properties, with methods you still ought to use good old `this`.

Comment: No, `@method()` is fine as is `@method some_arg`, they will be translated to `this.method()` and `this.method(some_arg)` respectively.